# Currency module step by step guide

Tags: 7

I want to provide a block where user can convert the currencies as desired and get the latest conversion rate.

I'm using [Currency](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency) module. But there is no any set up guide for it, so I'm unable to use it. Can somebody tell me how to set it up?

If it is not possible in this module, is there any other module?

Comment: Go to  administer >> settings >> currency and you can change the configuration settings

Comment: I saw there as well but I don't find anything to set it up as a block or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use below modules :

1. [Yahoo! Finance currency converter](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency_yahoo_finance)

> This module provides Currency with currency exchange rates through
>   Yahoo! Finance, which are updated continually throughout the trading
>   day.

2. [Currency Converter](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency_converter)

> Currency converter module was created for quick currency convertation.
>   It contains 10 currensies.
>
> It is flexibly configurable block. The currency undertakes from
>   several banks (on a choice).

3. [Open Exchange Rate Money.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/moneyjs)

> This module provides support for the money.js currency conversion
>   script from http://josscrowcroft.github.io/money.js/ along with
>   support for the Open Exchange Rate currency conversion data.

4. [Exchange Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/exchange_rate)

> Exchange Rate API is an extensible module that allow users to display
>   and manage the exchange rate in countries from around the world.
>
> Is common to see tools that present the official exchange rate, the
>   problem is that each bank has his own rate, for this reason it is
>   important to have a tool that can show the different variations across
>   multiple financial institutions.

Comment: I'm trying those modules. Will let you know if there's any result.

Comment: I tried using Currency Converter module. It works great. I tried to patch the module for other currencies (JPY, INR, etc.) I used https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/%5Badditional%20currencies%20and%20typo%20fix%5D-%5B1324270%5D-%5B4%5D.patch this patch but while patching, it says that patch applied partially. So it is not reflecting the extra currencies. Do partially patched files work?

Comment: Can anybody please take a look in https://www.drupal.org/node/1324270#comment-9971755

Comment: Tried using all the modules. 
(1) Yahoo! Finance currency converter - No steps to set up
(2) Currency Converter - Works great, but could not apply patch to enable other currencies.
(3) Open Exchange Rate Money.js - is paid version, so couldn't test it 
(4) Exchange Rate - supposed to be working only for Costa Rica, Genosha

Comment: I used the currency converter module and manually changed the code for required currencies.